# php auto rss feed filemtime error stat failed

Tags: php

I have a php code that automatically generates an RSS feed XML file. Now I have my pages which are in a folder. I read them out with simple php to generate title, links, description... that all goes fine and the code works great. But when I try to get the last timestamp of the file itself I get errors. I really can't figure out why the code gives errors.

```
<?php
$rssfeed = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<rss version='2.0'>
<channel>
        <title>My RSS feed</title>
        <link>http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/</link>
        <description>This is an example RSS feed</description>
        <language>en-us</language>
        <copyright>Copyright (C) 2009 mywebsite.com</copyright>
";
$links = scandir('../pages/');
$links = array_diff($links, array('.', '..', 'subpages', 'protected'));
foreach($links as $link){
$descr = file_get_contents('../description/' . $link);
$descr = str_replace(array('\\'), array(''), $descr);   
$pub = date ('F d Y H:i:s.', filemtime($link));
    $rssfeed .= "<item>
            <title>".$link."</title>
<description>".$descr."</description>
<link>http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/index.php?p=".$link."</link>
            <pubDate>".$pub."</pubDate>
                </item>";
}

    $rssfeed .= "</channel></rss>";
file_put_contents("../RSSfeed.xml", $rssfeed, LOCK_EX);
?>
```

this is the error I get:

> Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for 01Home in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\admin\rss.php on line 35

(localhost on a easyphp server for testing)